# How to use rsync between remote machines when one requires VPN

Tags: ssh, vpn, rsync

I have access to two supercomputing resources between. I know that the command structure should look like:

```
scp -r cwr0408@oakley.osc.edu:/fs/lustre/cwr0408 /scratch/gfm12
```

OR

```
rsync -auv -e ssh --progress /source/dir/ user@dest.com:/dest
```

As far as I can tell there are three ways to do this:

1. From the terminal in the local machine calling the two remote machines with a VPN connection to the network where the network restricted machines is

   This type of command would likely require the Cisco VPN client to interact with rsync or at least be running before calling rsync.
2. From the terminal in the remote machine via ssh which has no VPN requirements

   The supercomputer without VPN requirements does not have the Cisco client installed, and all attempts to install it fail without root.
3. From the terminal in the remote machine via ssh which has VPN requirements. This is the most feasible.

I made attempts at the first and the third to no avail.  Has anyone done this successfully?  What about in the case that both systems require separate VPNs?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, 1 super computer cannot access the other super conputer because of the VPN. Your desktop can access both super computers because you have the Vpn on your desktop.

Have you tried something like this?

ssh you@machine1 'tar cf - stuff-to-send' | ssh you@machine2 'tar xvf -'

Of course, that runs everything through your desktop, but that may be unavoidable.